# How to have multiple Where but with OR operator in Codeigniter 4 model?

Tags: php, model, codeigniter-4

i would like to have this query
`select ID, Username from tblUsers where ID = %1 OR Username = %1`

in Codeigniter 4 model.

i found that Codeigniter model support multiple where, but it using "AND" operator.
and i would like to avoid using Query builder.

is this can be done?
thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you would prefer to avoid using the  *Query builder*?

Comment: i want to utilize the model natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the string into the where
`$yourmidel->where("ID = %1 OR Username = %1");`

And if something which your are passing into query string must be in ***double `""` or single `''` quoted***.

Like `username = '%1'`

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just pointing you to the correct locations in the userguide

**OrWhere**
[There is an Or Where -  $builder->orWhere() in the users guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Search for $builder->orWhere() on that page

**Write your own queries**
[To write your own queries you can use something like $db->query](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#id2)

**Binding of query parameters**
[Binding of query parameters](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings)