# Codeigniter 4 - WHERE clause in Model

Tags: sql, chat, codeigniter-4

It's me again, Van.
Hi everyone,
I hope you're doing well!
I am doing a tutorial on a chat application using Codeigniter 4 with Ajax.
Everything worked fine until I applied the following code in the Model below

```
    public function load_chat_data($sender_id,$receiver_id) {
//        $where = ['sender_id' => $sender_id, 'receiver_id' => $receiver_id];
        
 
        $where1 = "sender_id = $sender_id OR sender_id = $receiver_id";
        $where2 = "receiver_id = $receiver_id OR receiver_id = $sender_id";
        
        $builder = $this->db->table('chat_messages');  
//      $builder->where($where);
        $builder->where($where1);
        $builder->where($where2);
        $builder->orderBy('chat_messages_id','ASC');
        $results = $builder->get();
        $rows = $results->getResultArray();
        if($rows > 0)
        {
            return $rows;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
```

The lines that I commented worked well before they were commented but it was not enough data I wanted to get so I tried to get both data of sender and receiver to display on the view by adding more code. However, when I tried `$where1` and `$where2` for the WHERE clauses, it didn't work. I think it must be the syntax error. Please correct my codes or any ideas on how the codes work with the same meaning supposed.
Thank you so much!!!

I tried as below, but it still didn't work.

```
$where1 = "sender_id={$sender_id} OR sender_id={$receiver_id}";
$where2 = "receiver_id={$receiver_id} OR receiver_id={$sender_id}";
```

Also, I tried:

```
$where1 = "'sender_id'=$sender_id OR 'sender_id'=$receiver_id";
$where2 = "'receiver_id'=$receiver_id OR 'receiver_id'=$sender_id";
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have multiple Where but with OR operator in Codeigniter 4 model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71795182/how-to-have-multiple-where-but-with-or-operator-in-codeigniter-4-model)

Comment: [$builder->where()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#builder-where)

Comment: Thank you for giving me those links above. It works now by using these two lines below: 
$builder->where('(sender_id = "'.$sender_id.'" OR sender_id = "'.$receiver_id.'")');
        $builder->where('(receiver_id = "'.$receiver_id.'" OR receiver_id = "'.$sender_id.'")');

Comment: Thank you so much, Steven! Have a good day, and see you next discussions!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to receive the messages of the conversation between two people. Can you try the following code for this?

```
$builder->groupStart(); // or $builder->orGroupStart();
$builder->where('sender_id', $sender_id);
$builder->where('receiver_id', $receiver_id);
$builder->groupEnd();

$builder->orGroupStart();
$builder->where('sender_id', $receiver_id);
$builder->where('receiver_id', $sender_id);
$builder->groupEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you, Savaş Dersim Çelik!
Yes, I was trying to make a chat application, and I did it after solving this issue. Now it's working well! But I will try to apply what you recommended and see if there's any difference.